# jQuery replace string from ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm trying to replace all instances of one string with another. Here is what I have so far:

I load template html file via ajax, and this is the content:

```
<div style="background-image:url({URL}/photo.png)">
    <div>
        <p>
           <h1>
             <a href="{URL}">link 1</a>
           </h1>
        </p>
        <a href="{URL}">link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically I need to replace all instances of {URL} with actual url.

I have tried something like this:

```
$.get("template.html")
    .done(function(data) {
        data.replace("/{URL}/g", "http://example.com");
});
```

or:

```
$.get("template.html")
    .done(function(data) {
        $(data).html($(data).html().replace("{URL}", "http://example.com"));
});
```

but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for using global replacement is not `data.replace("/{URL}/g", "http://example.com");` The correct syntax is: `data.replace(/{URL}/g, "http://example.com");`

I tried the below code and it works as expected:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function () {
            $.get("template.html", )
                .done(function (data) {
                    data = data.replace(/{URL}/g, "http://yourdomain.com");
                    $("#content").html(data);
                                });
                });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that `data.replace()` function will not change the actual content of `data` object thus I wrote `data = data.replace(/{URL}/g, "http://yourdomain.com");` then I inserted the modified contents inside the `div` tag.
Finally, in your `template.html` file, the first line should be like this:`<div style="background-image:url('{URL}/photo.png)'">` because url() expects a string!

Kindly refer to [JavaScript String replace() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) for more details.

Comment: Did you check if `data` object is returning `template.html` content or not? sometimes you face C.O.R.S issues with these requests. I passed your content to `data.replace(/{URL}/g, "http://example.com");` and I got the desired result.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using python3.5/django2.0.

It works for me only with single quotes. I try without quotes and with double quotes but did not work:

name`var url = '{% url "api_call" "str_to_replace" %}';  $.ajax({         url: url.replace('str_to_replace',"new string"),`